# correct expressjs and angular $http path

Tags: angularjs, http, express, server

My project structure looks like this:

- node_modules
- server.js
- public

  - css
  - scripts
  - index.html
  - modules

And in modules dir

- authentication
- home

  - views
  - controllers.js

Two files which are important in this case are:

1. server.js
2. controllers.js

In server.js I have this function:

```
app.get('/conn', function (req, res) {


   db.on('error', function (err) {
      res.json(err);
   });

   db.on('connect', function () {
      res.json('database connected')
   }) });
```

And function in controllers.js

```
        $http.get('/conn').success(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
```

On localhost everything works fine, but when i put files on server i have that error:

> GET http://xxxxxxxxxxxx/conn 404 (Not Found)

I know that problem is link to server.js, but how make it corretctly? How make path to file which is outside "public" directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem a time ago. The reason why i have that problem was the name of my server file. I use name "server.js" but I don't know why but my hosting operate only if server file has name "app.js"

Answer (score 0):

In your `controllers.js` you only specify the relative path to `/conn`. This works fine on localhost, but when on a server, the users will only have access to whats in your `public` folder. So when they trigger the `$http.get('/conn')` from their computer the relative path does not make sense.

What to do:
Use absolute url paths for your http-requests.

When you deploy to server you need to change from

```
$http.get('localhost:[portnr]/conn')
```

to

```
$http.get('http://<server-address>/conn')
```

I usually create a factory to keep my serverconfig:

```
angular
    .module("app")
    .factory("ServerConfig", [ServerConfig]);

function ServerConfig(){
    "use strict";

    var http = "http://";
    var base = "localhost:8080"; //Change this to server-address when deploying.

    return {
        host: http + base
    };
}
```

So all my $http request looks like this:

```
$http.get(ServerConfig.host + '/conn') // Or whatever path
```

Comment: I make a test and put server.js to public dir. In controller I try use $http.get("/conn") and  $http.get("/server.js/conn") and that simply doen't work and show the same error (404). I think that I have problem with routing in expressjs.

Comment: Can you include your server.js in your post?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Ntwwq00i

Server.js has more function but in this case importatnt are only this which i paste :)

Comment: I am not sure if this has anything to do with your problem but I think you should specify a path here: `app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));`. Like this: `app.use("/", express.static(__dirname + "/public"));`

Comment: In your first comment I see you have tried `$http.get('/server.js/conn')`. This won´t work because $http should take a URL as a parameter.  In my answer above ´<server-address>´ refers to either the domain-address of your server (e.g. htttp://mydomain.com) or an IP-address.

Comment: I know but I just try different things;) I have an error like this: "angular.js:11756 GET http://xxxxxxx.com/conn 404 (Not Found)" and this looks like link. Of course it throw error because i don't have any file with name "conn" and 404 error is quite clear. But how make $http.get('/conn') interpret like route to server.js function instead of file name.

Comment: This is because the server.js file runs on the server. The angular code runs client-side. So for the angular-code to access `/conn` in `server.js` the $http.get-call must include the address to the server where server.js is running.

Comment: OK, now I understand this, but when I use code from your first request I have the same error but it thrown GET xxxxxxx.com/undefined/conn 404 (Not Found) instead of GET xxxxxxx.com/conn 404 (Not Found)